# GoogleMap API key only works with debug key

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi, i’m new to the development of android sdk, i’m facing some problem, when i use the dubug API key, it works , but when i use my own complied API keystore, what i get is only the grey grid, **firewall, antivirus i already switched off**, and i tried many times re-assigned the key, and get the new API key, but it still can’t works.

hope someone here would help me, i’ll appreciate alot . =(
thanks.

regards
patrick

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "compiled API keystore", the map will only load if the app is installed from the market.  launching your app while debugging with a "compiled" api keystore will result in the grey grid.

rest assured, that once you deploy your application on the market, the map will work.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me! Adding more details of my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow this [Mapkey](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) it must work. are you getting the footprint of the right keystore?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had the same problem and I figured there wasn't any helpful answer around on the internet. So, hope this helps everyone:

When using `GoogleMaps for Android`, you need two keys - debug and release.

The "debug" key is kind of a misleading term. This key is also to be used when you develop the app in Eclipse. So essentially, use the debug key for development, testing, debugging.

When you're ready to launch the app to Market, set the `android:debuggable="false"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and use the Signed API key.

When using the signed API key, the  `MapView` will show up ONLY when the app is installed from the `Android Market`. So, installing the app from `Eclipse` (Run As, Debug As, etc) or command line `(adb install)` won't show the `MapView`. Rest assured, once the app is in the Market - you download it and the `MapView` will show up.

With the signed API key, if you deploy the app from Eclise, you will get a "Server returned 3, IOProcessing Exception 26" as a warning - just ignore it.

Note: Also ensure there are no duplicate instances of the same MapView. If your app needs to `MapView`s, use different sets of keys since GoogleMaps has a query limit for a single `MapView` instance.

For getting both the keys, follow the steps for [Obtaining API keys for GoogleMaps on Android](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).